# Configuring Nagios

Tags: nagios

We're using Nagios based Op5 to monitor hosts. I've minimum requirement to check a host if it is live or not.

So I simply want to know if a host is live with max RTA of 10 seconds. I don't care how long it takes care to respond to ICMP requests.

I've tried these commands:

```
time /opt/plugins/check_ping -H ns1.linode.com     -i 1000 -n 30
```

it exits in 10 seconds with output

> CRITICAL - ns1.linode.com: rta nan, lost
>   100%|rta=0.000ms;200.000;500.000;0; pl=100%;40;80;;
>
> ```
> real    0m10.006s
> user    0m0.001s
> sys     0m0.008s
> ```

When I tried with

```
 time /opt/plugins/check_ping -H ns1.linode.com   -c 10000,100% -w 10000,100%  -i 1000 -n 21
```

or  `time /opt/plugins/check_ping -H ns1.linode.com   -c 11s,100% -w 11s,100%  -i 1000 -n 29`

both of these exit in 10.013 and 10.006 seconds respectively. So even changing those option it seems it exits in only 10 seconds max( don't know why). I expect it to be something like value of i * value of n.

Answer (score 3):

First, read the --help output of check_ping (all of the standard plugins have --help output). Or read [the online help page](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_ping.html).

**So what is the right way to configure Ping command to fail only for RTA beyond 10 second?**

It's taking 10 seconds to run because you're not getting any ping replies, and the default timeout of the plugin is 10 seconds. Try it with a host you can actually ping, like something on the local network. To increase this timeout, you use the -t flag.

**So in this case what is the difference between -c and -w option?**

-c is for critical, -w is for warning. See the --help output of check_ping (all of the standard plugins have --help output). This is a fundamental concept for using Nagios.

Comment: I did read the -t option. It isn't intuitive for non-admin people. All it says is "Seconds before connection times out"